# Howto compare slot_type in boost::signal2

Tags: c++, boost, stl

If you connect to a signal using differnt funktions (to be called), how can one check if the function is already connected?
Usually i would compare the address of the function pointer, but how can i access that pointer?

Example:

```
boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;

sig.connect(Callback1());
sig.connect(Callback2());
```

So howto avoid another call of

```
sig.connect(Callback1());
```

?

Comment: I have tried to call the disconnect first but i get an compiler error while looking for a == operator in function_equal_impl to compare the slots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `boost::signals2::connection` object vaiable to store the connection of a signal with a slot, so you can to do it like this:

```
boost::signals2::connection c = sig.connect(Callback1());
// another call
if (! c.connected()){
     sig.connect(Callback1());
} else {
     cout << "signal with this slot is connected! << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can I check if it is exactlty connected with Callback1()?